# override sessionHandler using http:listener-config

Tags: mule

I need to migrate a http *NoSessionConnector* defined in mule 3.3.1 in this way:

```
<http:connector name="NoSessionConnector">
    <service-overrides sessionHandler="org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler" />
</http:connector>
```

to the new http:listener-config but I cannot put *service-overrides* inside http:listener-config tag nor inside http:listener tag. Both configurations are not permitted:

```
<http:listener-config name="httpListener" host="localhost">
    <service-overrides sessionHandler="org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler" />
</http:listener-config>

<http:listener config-ref="httpListener" path="/ecommerce/*">
    <service-overrides sessionHandler="org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler" />
</http:listener>
```

is there a way to configure a custom sessionHandler in mule 3.7.0? I need it to avoid a OptionalDataException as described on this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850187/mule-serialization-exception-while-making-outbound-call)

Comment: Do you still get that exception using the listener?

Comment: I get this error in *listener* `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 54; columnNumber: 79; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'service-overrides'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http":response-builder, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http":error-response-builder}' is expected.`

Comment: That's because it does not support it. But what is the error without having the ```service-overrides```?

Comment: Default sessionHandler creare a MULE_SESSION inbound property. This property is passed as HTTP header to a SOAP call I make later. Server side I have a MULE 3.3 server that cannot deserialize the MULe_SESSION value throwing a OptionalDataException as described on link

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant the error using the listener without the server overrides. I'm curious because that error with the SessionHandler happened with the old HTTP transport. Is it still occurring using the listener instead? What's the stack trace?

Comment: The error happens on a 3.3 installation, i mean, I'm tring to migrate an app that is a REST proxy to a SOAP service. The SOAP service is still hosted on a 3.3 installation and the OptionalDataException happens there. I need to let the 3.7 and 3.3 live together without changing anythiing on 3.3 until I finish migration for all apps

Comment: Then is the problem the HTTP header that is generated from the MULE_SESSION inbound property?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is the message property "MULE_SESSION" that is past as HTTP header, then you can try removing it from the outbound scope of the message in order to avoid sending "MULE_SESSION" as HTTP header. You can do it by using the "message-property-transformer" element:

```
<message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
    <delete-message-property key="MULE_SESSION" />
</message-properties-transformer>
```

Remember that you have to place it before the SOAP call in the flow.